# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n(-1)^{n-k+1}}{n-k}{n-1 \choose k} = 1$

Tags: summation

To finish a proof i have been working on i must prove the following:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n(-1)^{n-k+1}}{n-k}{n-1 \choose k} = 1
$$

I have checked that it does work empirically, but of course that is not good enough. Any suggestions on strategies for proving this summation would be just as appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: The binomial theorem can be applied once you get it into the right form. The $\frac{n}{n-k}$ can combine with $\binom{n-1}{k}$ into a single binomial coefficient.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt of course! i was thinking for some reason that the denominator of the binomial coefficient (when put into factorial form) would be $k!(n-k)!$ for some reason, must be because i'm tired

Comment: @HughDenoncourt you can prove now through answer if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n-k}{n-1\choose k}(-1)^{n-k+1}&=
-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{\cancel{n-k}}\left[\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots \cancel{(n-k)}}{1\cdot 2\cdots k}\right](-1)^{n-k}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}(-1)^{n-k}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose n-k}(-1)^{n-k}\qquad\text{using symmetry}\\
&=-\sum_{r=1}^{n}{n\choose r}(-1)^r\qquad\qquad \text{where $r=n-k$}\\
&=-\bigg\lbrace\left[\sum_{r=0}^{n}{n\choose r}(-1)^r\right]-{n\choose 0}\bigg\rbrace\\
&=-\left[(1-1)^n-1\right]\\
&=1\qquad \blacksquare\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the upvotes! :)